# Неровно ложится градиент CSS

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Хочу поставить линейный градиент на бэкграунд, но, к сожалению, выходит не то, что хотелось бы. Код прост и краток:

```css
body {
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #090979, #0044aa, #0074cf, #00a4ea, #00d4ff);
}

.header { 
 display: block;
 height: 180px;
}

.content-1 {
 display: block;
 
 float: right;
 width: 50%;
 height: 450px;
}

.content-2 {
 width: 50%;
 display: block;
 
 height: 450px;
}

.footer {
 display: block;
 
 height: 200px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Index Page</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
   <span>хедер</span>
  </div>

  <div class="content-1">
   контент1
  </div>

  <div class="content-2">
   контент2
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
   подвал
  </div>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

если просмотреть этот код здесь, то вроде бы всё выглядит нормально(а может не прогрузилось), но у меня на практике всё выглядит так:

[image: вот так выглядит на практике]

Comment: Google Chrome, другие не пробовал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пропишите в стиль:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Ваш градиент не достаёт до низа документа потому, что сам документ обрывается по высоте содержимого.

И в вашем случае ещё для body нужен `margin: 0;`

Comment: Приведите пример, когда при разработке под современные браузеры нужны префиксы.

Comment: Ваш вариант не работает. Можете сами сделать страницу с кодом из вопроса и вставить туда ваш стиль, градиент будет обрываться внизу.

Comment: @Sevastopol', не у всех стоит задача охватить 100% клиентов. Например на моём личном проекте охват 90%, потому что оставшиеся 10% в любом случае будут испытывать проблемы как ни старайся и современного сервиса получить не смогут, поэтому ими можно пожертвовать ради лучшей работы у остальных.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за помощь, очень признателен за советы и некоторую информацию, учту для себя на будущее. @Sevastopol' отдельное спасибо, твоё решение сработало!

Comment: может тогда принять в виде ответа, если сработало ?

Answer (score -1):

Нужно добавить соответствующие префиксы к `linear-gradient`:

```
-webkit-smth
-khtml-smth
-moz-smth
-ms-smth
-o-smth
smth
```

А именно:

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(to right bottom, #090979, #0044aa, #0074cf, #00a4ea, #00d4ff);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right bottom, #090979, #0044aa, #0074cf, #00a4ea, #00d4ff);
background-image: -khtml-linear-gradient(to right bottom, #090979, #0044aa, #0074cf, #00a4ea, #00d4ff);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to right bottom, #090979, #0044aa, #0074cf, #00a4ea, #00d4ff);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to right bottom, #090979, #0044aa, #0074cf, #00a4ea, #00d4ff);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to right bottom, #090979, #0044aa, #0074cf, #00a4ea, #00d4ff);
background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #090979, #0044aa, #0074cf, #00a4ea, #00d4ff);
```

Дополнительно еще (на основе не совсем верного ответа @Pavel Grishaev) добавить на случай, если контент вашей страницы заполнен меньше, чем на высоту окна:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Для градиентов до сих пор нужны префиксы? Уже несколько лет их не пишу - https://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient

Comment: опять есть нюанс, если задавать как вы говорите min-height вместо height, то потом внутри блоки не смогут растягиваться по высоте на 100%, как-будто не понимают откуда брать высоту для вычислений, так как ни на каком уровне родителей нет этого конкретного числа.